# Want to create byte array in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to create a byte array in objective c, i am not able to find equivalent code of java's ByteArrayOutputStream and DataOutputStream.
for eg..

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
dos.writeLong(counter); //counter is a long data type for eg 1165620611
dos.flush();
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
return data;
```

this code actually returns eight byte array...Here's the output in java
[0,0,0,0,69,121,-11,-125]

this is what i want exactly in objective c..

Answer (score 7):

```
// #1 long to char array
long l = 1165620611;
char bytes[sizeof(long)];
memcpy(bytes,&l,sizeof(l));

// #2 char array to nsdata
int size = sizeof(bytes)/sizeof(char);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:size];

// #3 nsdata to char array
char buffer[size];
[data getBytes:buffer length:size];

// #4 prints char array: 0 0 0 0 69 121 -11 -125
while (0<size--) {
    NSLog(@"%d",buffer[size]);
}
```

NSData is not needed at all, you can skip steps #2 and #3.

Answer (score 5):

use char `buff[]` array in objective - c

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) & [NSMutableData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html) classes for this.

> **NSData and its mutable subclass NSMutableData provide data objects,
>   object-oriented wrappers for byte buffers.** Data objects let simple
>   allocated buffers (that is, data with no embedded pointers) take on
>   the behavior of Foundation objects.
>
> NSData creates static data objects, and NSMutableData creates dynamic
>   data objects. NSData and NSMutableData are typically used for data
>   storage and are also useful in Distributed Objects applications, where
>   data contained in data objects can be copied or moved between
>   applications.
>
> The size of the data is subject to a theoretical limit of about 8
>   ExaBytes (in practice, the limit should not be a factor).
>
> NSData is “toll-free bridged” with its Core Foundation counterpart,
>   CFDataRef. See “Toll-Free Bridging” for more information on toll-free
>   bridging.